# How can I implement assert macro as a method?

Tags: c++, methods, macros, assert

I want implement assert macro as a method in C++ like .NET Framewrk.

For example in C# we can invoke assert method like this:

```
Debug.Assert(index > -1);
```

and I want implement assert something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
class debug
{
  public:

    static void my_asset(<condition>) // like assert macro
    {
      // ?
    }
};
```

When using this class:

```
debug::my_asset(index > -1); // Actually should be called assert(index > -1);
```

Thanks

**Edit**:

I want when invoking `debug::my_asset(index > -1);`, It shows correct file name and line number, and it works like C++ asset macro.

Comment: You can't do it and retain all the functionality of a macro (knowing what line and file it was called from, knowing what the text of the condition is, etc).

Comment: Why do you want to use a method? There's probably a way to get what you want (and still keep all the benefits of a macro) using some combination of a macro and other code.

Comment: @Owen: I want write my code fully object oriented :D

Comment: @Amir object oriented programming isn't something to stick to religiously. It can't do everything, as you have discovered.

Comment: I think you might have to compromise on this one ;)

Comment: @Amir: And by what justification? Is it really "object-oriented" to stick your function in a class? You're still just calling a function anyway. No objects need to exist or be modeled to call that function.

Comment: Filename and line number are not part of the language standard, so I'd say there's no way around a non-language (i.e. macro) solution.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: § 16.8 `The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation: __cplusplus, __DATE__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __STDC_HOSTED__, __TIME__.  The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation: __STDC__, __STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__, __STDC_VERSION__, __STDC_ISO_10646__.`

Comment: I just reread and reread your post, and realized what you meant.  Your idea is correct, wording is arguable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get the line number, file, and text version is via macro.  However:

```
#include <assert.h>
class debug
{
public:
    static void my_assert(bool passed, const char* assert, const char* file, long line)
    {
        if (passed == false)
            std::cout<<"failed assert "<<assert<<" in "<<file<<" at "<<line<<".\n";
    }
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define myassert(x) my_assert(true, "", "", 0)
#else 
    #define myassert(x) my_assert(x, #x , __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#endif
};


int main() {
    debug::myassert(sizeof(int)==4);
    return 0,
}
```

This code works in an oddball way.  The first `x` is the assert expression itself, evaluating to true or false, to tell my_assert what to do.  The  `#x` is a magic preprocessor command that makes a char* version of `x`, so we can display it. `__FILE__` is replaced with the filename, and `__LINE__` is replaced with the line number.  (Since it's a macro, it has the same line number as the calling function).

When you type `debug::myassert(sizeof(int)==4);`, the preprocessor says "I know what `myassert(whatever)` is!" and replaces it.  So it replaces it all with: `debug::my_assert(sizeof(int)==4, "sizeof(int)==4", "main.cpp", 27);`, which is a valid line of code.  So if sizeof(int) is 8 for instance (it is on some machines), the first parameter is `false`, and the line is displayed "failed assert sizeof(int)==4 in main.cpp at 27."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want invoke it like `debug::my_asset(index > -1);`. With your code `myassert` is still a MACRO not a METHODE or METHODE LIKE.

Comment: (Also, it's method.  No trailing E)

Comment: That's COOL :-), But I couldn't understand why this code works?!

Answer (score 6):

There are several features of assert `assert` (in `<assert.h>` or `<cassert>`) that are of interest:

- that when you're compiling a release build, the assert tests aren't evaluated at all.
- the error message printed when an assertion fails can tell you the file and line number where your assertion failed
- it can also tell you the exact code that failed.

You can't do these in C++ without using a macro.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void my_asset(bool cond) // like assert macro
{
  ::assert(cond);
}
```

Doesn't work?

Comment: When assertion failed, the file name, file number and actual condition text does not shown correctly.

Comment: @Amir - of course not. You have to use the macro directly for that. Calling a macro preserves the file lines/names (because they're compiled in), calling a function doesn't. Don't know what about C#, but that's C++ for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
void debug::my_assert(bool cond) {
    ASSERT(cond);
}
```

This would work in that it would cause an exception when the assertion failed.

It's a little less helpful than the macro because `my_assert` can't see what the condition was that failed -- you'll get an assertion failure but no useful explanation (though you'll get an accurate stack trace in a debugger).

Also see Ken's reasons why a macro is more helpful.

Comment: When assertion failed, the file name, file number and actual condition text does not shown correctly.

Comment: Yes -- and it's not going to, unfortunately. Once you enter a method you lose all information about where you came from (but, if you use a debugger you'll be able to see the stack trace).